# PHP_MYSQL - Select between two query, according to a specific file

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna make a function who can make a select. But the problem is the first condition is always true. So I want to switch between this two select, according to the selected file.

```
<?php
function select_cat(){
    if (file('index_cms.php')){
        return "SELECT * FROM posts_anon";
    } elseif(file('category.php')){
        return "SELECT * FROM posts_anon WHERE category = '$_GET[cat_name]'";
    }
    return 1;
}

select_cat();
$run_side = mysqli_query($connexion, select_cat());
?>
```

Maybe someone can help me to fix that.
Thx.

Update :

Okay I found the solution, based on the post of Mazhar Hussain.

```html
<?php
function select_cat()
{
  if (isset($_GET['cat_name'])) {
    if ($_GET['cat_name'] == true && file('category.php')) {
        return "SELECT * FROM posts_anon WHERE category = '$_GET[cat_name]'";
      } else {
        return '';
      }
   } else {
    return "SELECT * FROM posts_anon";
   }
}
select_cat();
$run_side = mysqli_query($connexion, select_cat());
?>
```

I've changed the order. Firstly, I verify if there is something in $GET_['cat_name'], and if it matches with the file category.php. 
If everything it's okay, so use the second "SELECT".
If it doesn't match, return nothing or return the first "SELECT".

Thx everyone.

Comment: Do you want to check if the currently executed file is `index_cms` with `file('index_cms.php')`?

Comment: sorry dude.. Ive read that 4 times and I still have no idea what youre asking.

Comment: I just want to switch between file. if it's index.php, use this "SELECT", or if it's category.php, use the other "SELECT".

Comment: what is "switch between file" in your case? Did you mean if "user loads (in browser) index.php then execute this query, and if user loads category.php then execute another query"?

Comment: you can use isset funtion like this ...  if(isset(file('index_cms.php')))

Comment: @SergiyPetrov exactly

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are looking for is the script name currently being executed by server use some thing like below

```
<?php
function select_cat()
{
    $fname = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
    if ($fname == 'index_cms.php'){
        return "SELECT * FROM posts_anon";
    } elseif($fname == 'category.php'){
        return "SELECT * FROM posts_anon WHERE category = '$_GET[cat_name]'";
    }
    return 1;
}

select_cat();
$run_side = mysqli_query($connexion, select_cat());
?>
```

Comment: that return nothing :(

Comment: echo the $fname and adjust the file name accordingly